# Assign Recordset to Variable in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, recordset

I am trying to assign variables value from recordset and insert values into an Access table. I also need to clear the table and insert new set of data before inserting. The recordset is from a stored procedure in SQL Server. Following does not seem to work:

```vb
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection, cmd As ADODB.Command, rst As 
ADODB.Recordset
Dim Itm As String, JobNo As Integer, RevNo As Integer, DUStatus As Date, LDUStatus As Date, UTrigger As String


Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider='sqloledb';Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog='Database';Integrated Security='SSPI';"
conn.Open


Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CommandText = "rg_ItemsQuerySP"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@JobNo", adInteger, adParamInput, , TempJobNo)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@RevNo", adInteger, adParamInput, , TempRevNo)
End With

Set rst = cmd.Execute

If rst.EOF Then Exit Function
rst.MoveLast
rst.MoveFirst
    With rst
      Do While Not .EOF

            Itm = rst.Fields("Item")
            JobNo = rst.Fields("Job No")
            RevNo = rst.Fields("Revision No")
            DUStatus = rst.Fields("DateUpdatedStatus")
            LDUStatus = rst.Fields("LastDateUpdatedStatus")
            UTrigger = rst.Fields("UpdateTrigger")

        DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO ItemsQuerySP_Temp values " & Itm & ", " & JobNo & ", " & RevNo & ", " & DUStatus & ", " & LDUStatus & ", " & UTrigger & ";")
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
    End With

   conn.Close
   Set conn = Nothing
```

Comment: What is your question? You post code without telling us the issues or problems you face.

Comment: Unless all your values are numeric, some of them will need quotes.  And I think you also need parentheses around the list of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly your issue is the lack of quotes around string variables which would raise SQL error. Since you use ADO parameters, continue to use parameters via [QueryDef](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/parameters-collection-dao), avoiding string concatenation (i.e., ampersands) or punctuation (i.e., quotes):

**SQL** *(save below as an MS Access saved query, adjust types as needed: `Text`, `Long`, `Double`, etc.)*

```sql
PARAMETERS PrmItm Text, PrmJobNo Text, PrmRevNo Text, 
           PrmDUStatus Text, PrmLDUStatus Text, PrmUTrigger Text;
INSERT INTO ItemsQuerySP_Temp 
VALUES(PrmItm, PrmJobNo, PrmRevNo, 
       PrmDUStatus, PrmLDUStatus, PrmUTrigger)
```

**VBA** *(relevant section)*

```vb
Dim qdef AS QueryDef

' ... same as above...
Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery") 

With rst
   Do While Not .EOF

        ' BIND PARAMETERS
        qdef!PrmItm = rst.Fields("Item")
        qdef!PrmJobNo = rst.Fields("Job No")
        qdef!PrmRevNo = rst.Fields("Revision No")
        qdef!PrmDUStatus= rst.Fields("DateUpdatedStatus")
        qdef!PrmLDUStatus = rst.Fields("LastDateUpdatedStatus")
        qdef!PrmUTrigger = rst.Fields("UpdateTrigger")

        ' EXECUTE ACTION
        qdef.Execute dbFailOnError
        .MoveNext
   Loop
End With

Set qdef = Nothing
```

Comment: It seems to be working but it goes into an infinite loop while inserting data to the ItemsQuerySP_Temp table. It is inserting same record infinitely. What could have gone wrong?

Comment: You have to incorporate `Recordset.MoveNext`. See edit. I hadn't realized I left it out.

Comment: Works great now! Thanks!